# Cannot browse certain sites from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ssl

The problem I have is that, suddenly, some websites stopped working (ffor example, I cannot log into HipChat nor Docker Hub).

I dug a lot, and this is what I found:

- DNS Resolution works fine.
- Problem appears to be related to some https POST connections.
- Connections can be opened and I get a "100 Continue" code from the other side, but nothing else happens: the connections stays open without any response.

I observed several things:

- I captured one of the failing requests (I can see them hung on Chrome developer tools) and curled it.

  - If I do it from my machine, I obtain a 502 error after a long wait.
  - If I do it from a machine in a different network, it works.
  - If I do it from my machine, connected into a VPN, it works.
  - If I do it from an other machine in the same LAN, it works.
- In all cases above, I ran curl using "-v" flag and TSL negotiation looks identical to the last character. It only changes after the "100 Continue" code: In the good ones I get a 200, and in the bad one I directly get a 502 after waiting about a minute. Also, openssl version is the same for all machines.
- I tracerouted the IP, and the only weird thing I can see is that when I do it from my machine there are a lot more hops than when I do it from the machine I have in a different network. However, if I traceroute it connected into the VPN, the hops are different but the number of them is similar.
- If I boot a Windows 7 virtual machine on top of my ubuntu desktop, it fails the same way as the host.

My specs are:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3, completely up-to-date.
- An ADSL (PPPoE) router which i connect to using Wifi.

What else can I look at or suspect from?

**UPDATE**

While troubleshooting the problem, it simply went away!

I had sniffed the network using wireshark and had found some "TCP ACKed unseen segment" errors which had made me suspicious about the wifi.

[image: TCP ACKed unseen segment]

In order to discard it, I connected my laptop using a wire and disconnected the Wifi, and the problems actually banished.
However, when I disconnected the wire and switched the Wifi On again, the problem didn't come back!

So, I am not sure about it, but I suspect that a simply disable the wifi adapter and enabling it again might have solved the problem.

Note that I had rebooted my laptop a couple of times before and the problem persisted, so I guess that disabling the adapter from the OS might have reset something which was the origin of the problem.

I leave the question open anyway for if anyone wants to suggest other troubleshooting actions to consider.

Answer (score 1):

As I explain in the update, disabling and enabling again the Wifi Adapter from the OS has made the problem disappear.

Give it a try if you face a similar issue!

Comment: Yes. Same issue occurs with my machine today. I cannot browse some sites via Chrome and also cannot run some programs that uses ssl (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR). Disconnect/connect not works. But enable/disable Wi-Fi resolves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Comment: Restarting Wi-Fi resolves only bug with Chrome, but some programs not work. I found that the reason (at least in my case) was libnss3. After downgrading libnss3 to 3.19 all programs works fine (without net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR).